# gulp-sftp error on gulp-sftp

Tags: ftp, gulp, sftp

I have setup a gulp task with gulp-sftp and have tried two sites to connect to it without success. I have tried both with Filezilla and both are connecting.

My task is the following:

```
var sftp = require('gulp-sftp');        
gulp.task('sftp', function () {
        return gulp.src('dist/**/*')
            .pipe(sftp({
                host: 'waws-prod-sn1-015.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net',
                user: 'fwd16\$fwd16',
                pass: 'xxxxxx',
                remotePath: '/site/wwwroot'
            }));
    });
```

The respond I am getting is the following:

```
bash-3.2$ gulp sftp                                                                                                                            
[22:29:18] Using gulpfile ~/Desktop/gulp-starter-csstricks/gulpfile.js                                                                         
[22:29:18] Starting 'sftp'...                                                                                                                  
[22:29:18] Authenticating with password.                                                                                                       
[22:29:28] 'sftp' errored after 10 s                                                                                                           
[22:29:28] Error in plugin 'gulp-sftp'                                                                                                         
Message:                                                                                                                                       
    Timed out while waiting for handshake                                                                                                      
Details:                                                                                                                                       
    level: connection-timeout                                                                                                                  
[22:29:28] gulp-sftp SFTP abrupt closure                                                                                                       
[22:29:28] Connection :: close
```

I would prefer to use the auth method, as I prefer not to expose the user and pwd in the gulp file and I add the .ftppass to my .gitignore.

If I add the user and pwd in my .ftppass file and change the task to the following:

```
gulp.task('sftp', function () {
    return gulp.src('dist/**/*')
        .pipe(sftp({
            host: 'waws-prod-sn1-015.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net',
            authFile:'.ftppass',
            auth: 'keyMain',
            remotePath: '/site/wwwroot'
        }));
});
```

I get the following error:

```
bash-3.2$ gulp sftp                                                                                                                            
[22:22:55] Using gulpfile ~/Desktop/gulp-starter-csstricks/gulpfile.js                                                                         
[22:22:55] Starting 'sftp'...                                                                                                                  
[22:22:55] 'sftp' errored after 7.52 ms                                                                                                        
[22:22:55] SyntaxError: Unexpected token $ in JSON at position 36                                                                              
    at Object.parse (native)                                                                                                                   
    at module.exports (/Users/sohail/Desktop/gulp-starter-csstricks/node_modules/gulp-sftp/index.js:33:25)                                     
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/Users/sohail/Desktop/gulp-starter-csstricks/gulpfile.js:86:15)                                                       
    at module.exports (/Users/sohail/Desktop/gulp-starter-csstricks/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)                             
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/Users/sohail/Desktop/gulp-starter-csstricks/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)                      
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/Users/sohail/Desktop/gulp-starter-csstricks/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)                     
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/Users/sohail/Desktop/gulp-starter-csstricks/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)                         
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:129:20                                                                                     
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)                                                                              
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)                                                                              
    at Module.runMain (module.js:592:11)                                                                                                       
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)                                                                                                           
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)                                                                                                       
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

Anyone understand what I missing in my code?

-thanks
Sohail

Answer (score 0):

You must review this error line:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token $ in JSON at position 36

it seems a bad format in json.